# Need transfer number string from POI to Date string

Tags: java, date, apache-poi

By using POI, I got the date in string number format.
For example: for date "10/15/2012", I got "41197" as a string.
But what I need is "10/15/2012" as a string.
Is there any existing method I can use to do the conversion from "41197" to "10/15/2012".

Comment: Which method are you calling to get the date?

Comment: I'm using:                                                                           cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); cellValue=Tool.formatNumber(cell.getStringCellValue());

Comment: Did you try reading the [javadocs on the setCellType method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)? Only it has a pretty explicit warning not to do that for your use case, and tells you the proper solution to use instead...

Answer (score 1):

## Count Of Days Since Epoch

That number appears to be the number of days since an [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). But which epoch?

POI is a library for working with Microsoft Office documents. Different Microsoft product teams have unfortunately used different epochs.

- `January 0, 1900` Microsoft Excel
- `January 1, 1904` Microsoft Excel
- `January 1, 1` Microsoft .Net
- `December 30, 1899` Microsoft COM

To further confuse things, the doc for Apache POI [`DateUtil`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html) [`absoluteDay`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#absoluteDay(java.util.Calendar,%20boolean)) talks about `1900/12/31`.

Be aware that Microsoft Excel observes the fictional date of February 29, 1900.

Explore that [`DateUtil`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html) class for conversion methods between Excel numbers, Java `Date`, and strings.

## Experiment

Here is some code using the Joda-Time 2.7 library to experiment with various epochs so we might guess which epoch is in play with your expected result.

Try these 3 epochs.

```
LocalDate epoch_1900_01_00 = new LocalDate( 1900, 1, 1 ).minusDays(1);
LocalDate epoch_1904_01_01 = new LocalDate( 1904, 1, 1 );
LocalDate epoch_1900_12_31 = new LocalDate( 1900, 12, 31 );

int countDays  = 41197;
```

Calculate results.

```
System.out.println (epoch_1900_01_00 + " + " + countDays + " days = " + epoch_1900_01_00.plusDays ( countDays ) );
System.out.println (epoch_1904_01_01 + " + " + countDays + " days = " + epoch_1904_01_01.plusDays ( countDays ) );
System.out.println (epoch_1900_12_31 + " + " + countDays + " days = " + epoch_1900_12_31.plusDays ( countDays ) );
```

When run.

```
1899-12-31 + 41197 days = 2012-10-16
1904-01-01 + 41197 days = 2016-10-16
1900-12-31 + 41197 days = 2013-10-16
```

If we subtract one for the fictional leap day, then first epoch of `1899-12-31` (or `January 0, 1900`) renders your expected value of 2012-10-15.

Comment: Tip: If doing further work in Java with those date-time values, be sure to learn about [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Avoid using java.util.Date and .Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is returning a numeric data you can convert them in date

Try this

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
    } else {
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
}
```